# C Program won't run - Beginners's Query on Pointers & Char

Tags: c

I am unable to run this program. I keep getting the error message(s):

> 10|warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat]|

Another one is:

> 6|warning: 's1' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|

```
int main()
{
    char *s1, *s2;
    *s1='p';
    *s2 ='q';
    printf("%d %d\n", sizeof(s1), sizeof(s2));
    printf("Value of *s1 = %c \n", *s1);
    printf("Address of *s1 = %u \n", s1);
    printf("Address of *s2 = %u \n", s2);
    return 0;
}
```

I am a beginner in C. Any help at explaining on what's wrong here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: maybe try: printf("Address of *s1 = %u \n", &s1);

Answer (score 3):

First, let me tell you, in your code,

```
*s1='p';
*s2 ='q';
```

both the instructions try to write into uninitialised memory area. It  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate memory to both `s1` and `s2` before you make use of them. maybe [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) can help.

That said,

- use `%zu` to print the output of `sizeof`, which is of type `size_t`.
- use `%p` to print an address, and cast the corresponding argument to `(void *)`

Answer (score 2):

Going through your errors:

> 10|warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'char *' [-Wformat]|

comes from the line

```
printf("Address of *s1 = %u \n", s1);
```

The `%u` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `unsigned int`.  The expression `s1` has type `char *` (because you declared it as `char *s1`).

A pointer is not an unsigned integer<sup>1</sup>, hence the warning.  To print out pointer values, use the `%p` conversion specifier and cast the argument to `void *`, like so:

```
printf("Address of *s1 = %p \n", (void *) s1);
```

This is probably the only time in C where you have to explicitly cast a pointer value to `void`.

> 6|warning: 's1' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|

You've declared `s1` as a pointer to `char`; its value will be an *address* in memory where the value `p` will be stored (`p` will not be stored to `s1` itself).  Unfortunately, you haven't initialized `s1` to point to a valid memory location; it contains an *indeterminate* value that doesn't correspond to the address of any object in your program.  Thus, when you write

```
*s1 = 'p';
```

you're trying to store the value `'p'` to an invalid memory location.

Since you're trying to figure out the differences between pointers and other variables, I'm going to suggest the following changes:

```
char s1, *s2;
s1 = 'p';
s2 = &s1;
```

So now the following are true:

```
*s2 ==  s1 == 'p'
 s2 == &s1
```

The *expressions* `*s2` and `s1` have type `char`, and the value of each is the character value `'p'`.

**EDIT** The expression `'p'` has type `int`, not `char`.  Oops.

The expressions `s2` and `&s1` have type `char *`, and the value of each is the *address* of `s1`.  The following memory map shows how this works (addresses are pulled out of thin air and don't represent any real-world system):

```
Item            Address          0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03
----            -------          ---- ---- ---- ----
  s1            0x10000000        'p'   ??   ??   ??  // ?? represents unknown byte value
  s2            0x10000004       0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

Then the rest of your code becomes something like this:

```
/**
 * If you have a c99 or later compiler, use %zu for size_t values,
 * otherwise use %lu and cast to unsigned long:
 *
 *  printf( "%lu %lu", (unsigned long) sizeof s1, (unsigned long) sizeof s2 );
 *
 * Note that sizeof is an operator, not a function; parentheses are only
 * required if the operand is a type name.  Thus
 *
 *  sizeof s1 == sizeof (char)
 *  sizeof s2 == sizeof (char *)
 *
 * Also note that the type of the character constant 'p'
 * is int, not char, so sizeof 'p' != sizeof s1.  
 */
printf("%zu %zu %zu\n", sizeof 'p', sizeof s1, sizeof s2);  

printf("Value of s1 = %c \n", s1);
printf("Value of s1 through s2 = %c\n", *s2 ); 
printf("Address of s1 = %p \n", (void *) &s1);
printf("Address of s1 through s2 = %p\n", (void *) s2 );
printf("Address of s2 = %p\n", (void *) &s2 );
```

---

<sup>1.  A pointer *value* (that is, an address) may fit in an `unsigned int` object (or not), but pointer *types* are distinct from integer types.</sup>